# Pandas - concatenate r with the filename not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pass the filepath as a variable with r on it.

This works for me,

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'\\ServerA\FolderA\DataFile.xlsx',sheet_name = Import_sheet_name)
```

But this doesn't

```
FileNameReq = '\\ServerA\FolderA\DataFile.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel (r + FileNameReq ,sheet_name = Import_sheet_name)
```

How Can I pass the filename as a variable separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/`:

```
file_path = '/ServerA/FolderA/DataFile.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel (file_path, sheet_name = Import_sheet_name)
```

Comment: I will accept the answer. It asks for 10 minutes. And I needed to add another "/" before the first "/". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second one doesn't work for you is that `\` is an escape character which means that in combination with other characters can give you special non-alphanumeric characters, like `\t` which gives you a tab or `\n` which gives a newline character or even `\a` which I think gives you a system beep.

As you've rightly pointed out there are two simple ways to solve this:

1. `FileNameReq = r"\\ServerA\FolderA\DataFile.xlsx"` using an r as a prefix (meaning raw string) means that the string is evaluated literally rather that escape sequences being parsed into special characters
2. Or simply change the direction of the slashes `FileNameReq = "//ServerA/FolderA/DataFile.xlsx"`